# Windows 2008 R2 - errors with "net localgroup" commands run from a service

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, net

I have a service that is behaving differently when run on windows 2008 R2 I believe it might be that the service installed on windows 2008 R2 is somehow having a slightly different context or holding different privileges The service creates a win32_process object that runs "net localgroup" commands. Those commands are failing when the server from which they are run is windows 2008 R2 the win32_process commands are remote to other servers So windows 2008 RTM - the service can execute the commands correctly. Move the same service to windows 2008 R2 they start to fail

Answer (score 0):

What kind of permission set does the account have that is running the service? Perhaps try elevating it a little.